# Connection Limit in MailChimp account

Tags: mailchimp

While exploring the MailChimp API, We came to know that the current connection limit is 10 simultaneous connections per user account. If Limit crosses then error message will be returned.

Is this limit same for free forever plan account and other price plans account?

Kindly let me know the answer.

Thanks 
Sonia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that limit exists for all accounts.

Comment: Thank you for quick response

Comment: I have nearly ten thousand email list in by database. I want to put those emails to mailchimp list. When I try to put those data that error occurred. How I fix this issue?